Закрыть доступ на определенный свой ip через iptables
Не могу понять как закрыть доступ на свой IP по определенному порту через IP tables.
В интернете все, что вбиваю, показывает только как для чужих IP закрыть или для интерфейса.
У меня с десяток ip адресов и мне надо для большинства закрыть доступ на 80 и 443 порты.
пробовал так
-A INPUT -d тутIP --dports 80,443 -j DROP 

не работает

Что такое определенный свой ip , как понимать У меня с десяток ip адресов и мне надо для большинства закрыть доступ на 80 и 443 порты.  Покажите схему, где какие интерфейсы, где firewall, где какие службы, адреса, порты.

Возможно перед запрещающим правилом, стоят разрешающие, потому и не работает.
